# JavaScript match substring after RegExp

Tags: javascript, regex, string, substring

I have a string that look something like

```
something30-mr200
```

I would like to get everything after the `mr` (basically the # followed by mr) *always there is going to be the `-mr`

Any help will be appreciate it.

Answer (score 19):

You can use a regexp like the one Bart gave you, but I suggest using match rather than replace, since in case a match is not found, the result is the entire string when using replace, while null when using match, which seems more logical. (as a general though).

Something like this would do the trick:

```js
function getNumber(string) {
    var matches = string.match(/-mr([0-9]+)/);
    return matches[1];
}
console.log(getNumber("something30-mr200"));
```

Answer (score 4):

```
var result = "something30-mr200".split("mr")[1];
```

or

```
var result = "something30-mr200".match(/mr(.*)/)[1];
```

Comment: You forgot to close the string `"mr`.

Answer (score 4):

Why not simply:

```
-mr(\d+)
```

Then getting the contents of the capture group?

Answer (score 2):

What about:

```
function getNumber(input) { // rename with a meaningful name 
    var match = input.match(/^.*-mr(\d+)$/);

  if (match) { // check if the input string matched the pattern
    return match[1]; // get the capturing group
  }
}

getNumber("something30-mr200"); // "200"
```

Comment: Wow, almost identical solution, practically at the same time. Cheers :).

Comment: Are you sure you want to test `match[1]`? This will be evaluated to *false* if it’s `0`.

Comment: @Gumbo: It wont evaluate false, because the matches are **Strings** not **Numbers**, it will only evaluate to false if match[1] is an empty string.

Comment: Heh, it would evaluate false if it would be a string containing '0' only in PHP, hence the confusion, probably. That's a stupid thing to do, btw.

Answer (score 1):

This may work for you:

```
// Perform the reg exp test
new RegExp(".*-mr(\d+)").test("something30-mr200");
// result will equal the value of the first subexpression
var result = RegExp.$1;
```

Comment: There's no need to include the first `.*` and the hyphen needs no escaping. This works as well: `"-mr(.*)"`. But the `.*` is dangerous: if there's a lot more text after `"-mr"` the `.*` will "eat" it. Of course, the OP wasn't really clear about what text could come after `"-mr"`.

Comment: That's a good point. I was assuming that the OP would want everything after the "-mr". I modified the code to remove the escape before the hyphen and restrict the subexpression to digits. I escape everything out of habit more than anything else. :)

Answer (score 0):

What about finding the position of -mr, then get the substring from there + 3?

It's not regex, but seems to work given your description?